# R - Numeric to Date gives wrong value

Tags: r, date, format

I have a data frame `DP` with a column `variable` in numeric format which is a numeric representation of Date.

Example: 43282 corresponds to 7/1/2018 (try in excel).

But in R when I call `as.Date()` to convert it to date, I get the wrong date

```
DP$Time <- as.Date(DP$variable)

  variable       Time
1    43282 2088-07-02
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Thanks a lot!!.  Guess origin was defaulted to '1970-01-01'  I changed it to origin = '1900-01-01' and it worked

Answer (score 3):

If it is based on excel, then change the `origin` from default `1970-01-01` to `1899-12-30`

```
as.Date(43282, origin = '1899-12-30')
#[1] "2018-07-01"
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel's origin of date is "1899-12-30" and R's origin of date is "1970-01-01". Since they have different origins for the date, while importing the data from Excel, you are getting a different date in R.

Specify the right origin and it will print the right values:

---

`DP$Time <- as.Date(DP$variable, origin = "1899-12-30")`